# Table in latex with superscript

Tags: tables

trying to rewrite table in latex, however I need rewrite sec1 columns into sec^1 (with superscript)

Thank you

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\title{tabulka}
\author{petr102030 Hrobar}
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{tabulka}
\begin{sidewaystable}[]
\caption{Instance do 1000 bodů}
\label{do1000}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{CNN}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{CNN-2-opt}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{PMSOM}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Instance} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Optimum}} & \textbf{sec1} & \textbf{\%rozdíl} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{TPDB}} & \textbf{sec1} & \textbf{\%rozdíl} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{TPDB}} & \textbf{k*} & \textbf{sec1} & \textbf{\%rozdíl2} & \textbf{TPDB} \\
eil51 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{426} & 0.019 & 18.78 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.004} & 0.019 & 4.23 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.001} & 1 & 0.31 & 1.64 & 0.005 \\
berlin52 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7 542} & 0.088 & 8.49 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.007} & 0.019 & \textbf{2.53} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.000} & 1 & 0.36 & 4.29 & 0.015 \\
eil76 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{538} & 0.110 & 13.94 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.015} & 0.042 & 7.25 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.003} & 1 & 0.67 & 3.72 & 0.025 \\
eil101 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{629} & 0.066 & 18.60 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.012} & 0.082 & 7.63 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.006} & 1 & 1.31 & 3.72 & 0.049 \\
lin105 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{14 379} & 0.231 & 17.80 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.041} & 0.094 & 5.30 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.005} & 1 & 1.11 & 3.00 & 0.033 \\
bier127 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{118 282} & 0.275 & 13.26 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.036} & 0.145 & 5.76 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.008} & 1 & 1.53 & 2.40 & 0.037 \\
ch130 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 110} & 0.269 & 17.82 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.048} & 0.190 & 5.09 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.010} & 2 & 4.53 & 2.39 & 0.108 \\
ch150 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 528} & 0.307 & 8.43 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.026} & 0.200 & \textbf{2.79} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.006} & 2 & 3.01 & 3.30 & 0.099 \\
rat195 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2 323} & 0.431 & 16.92 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.073} & 0.320 & 4.43 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.014} & 2 & 5.70 & 4.09 & 0.233 \\
d198 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{15 780} & 0.433 & 12.86 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.056} & 0.343 & 4.05 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.014} & 2 & 10.52 & 2.09 & 0.220 \\
pr299 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{48 191} & 0.873 & 20.95 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.183} & 1.362 & 6.02 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.082} & 2 & 7.81 & 3.99 & 0.312 \\
pcb442 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{50 778} & 2.093 & 16.10 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.337} & 2.621 & 6.06 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.159} & 2 & 11.13 & 5.54 & 0.617 \\
d493 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{35 002} & 2.431 & 18.56 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.451} & 5.017 & 5.49 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.275} & 3 & 19.52 & 4.55 & 0.889 \\
u574 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{36 905} & 3.506 & 20.62 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.723} & 7.651 & 7.83 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.599} & 3 & 30.51 & 3.94 & 1.201 \\
d657 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{48 912} & 4.950 & 23.63 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.170} & 12.671 & 6.62 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.839} & 3 & 22.22 & 4.32 & 0.960 \\
u724 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{41 910} & 6.410 & 21.94 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.406} & 13.839 & 5.77 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.798} & 3 & 21.41 & 5.30 & 1.136 \\
rat783 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8 806} & 7.872 & 21.61 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.701} & 11.748 & 7.81 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.918} & 3 & 19.55 & 6.15 & 1.203 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{1) stanoveno jako průměr z 10 měření} & 17.08 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.37} &  & 5.57 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0.22} &  &  & 3.79 & 0.42 \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{2) dle nejlepší hodnoty z 10 měření} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `$\mathbf{sec}^\mathbf{1}$` do what you want?

Comment: `\textsuperscript{1}`?

Comment: please do not repost the same question, you can edit a post if you need to add more information.